# Invert Text Color From Background Image

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a black, starry background and the navbar has white text. The navbar stays at the top when you scroll, and the links of the navbar become almost invisible when they pass over other images on the page because the navbar is transparent. How can I invert the color of the text based on whatever is directly behind it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `mix-blend-mode: difference;`, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/avdeoq97/

But it would be better to give your navbar a different background, like a dropshadow with a glass effect, so it can always be seen. The inverted colour alone might not be very accessible.

Comment: I do actually have a dropshadow, only on the bottom. How would I go about adding a translucent background? I already tried low-opacity grey or white, and it didn't look very good. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: `mixed-blend-mode: difference;` doesn't actually invert the color in real time based on the background. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: if you could share a reproducible, I could take a look. just from reading, i can all but guess, and I am out of guesses. As for the glass effect, check this out: https://css.glass